# Nullable types and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, nullable

For example, we have a model like this:

```
public class Trip : BaseEntity, ITrackChanges
{
    public string UniqueHash { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string InternalNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScheduledDateUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastDeliveryDateUtc { get; set; }

    public decimal? CalculatedDistance { get; set; }

    public decimal? FreightAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal? SellAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal? Tolls { get; set; }

}
```

we can see many decimal nullable properties. My opinion, that this property may be set, but may be not set and it's valid! It means, that Trip can be without CalculatedDistance, for example, this property can be calculated and saved in the future (or never). I use this entity class as code first class to generate SQL by Entity Framework. And it will be created as

```
[CalculatedDistance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
```

And, seems to me, it's correct. Then we can do any actions with this value, sum, other calculate actions etc

My team lead says, that we SHOULD NOT to have nullable types at all and store 0 instead of null. But 0 is value and if we use 0 (-1, -100, -100500 etc) we use a magic number really! We should remember, that 0 is not a value, but means, that value is not set! We already have "not set value", it's NULL. He argues it, that difficult to make SQL to Entities requests with nullable types. But I never have any problems with nullable types.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I agree with your team, especially the decimal values, as the default is zero anyhow.. yourmaking them nullable for no good reason that I see.

Comment: @Trey why no good reason?

Comment: I can't even spell entity framework but from the database side storing magic numbers is a bad idea. If a value is unknown then NULL is absolutely correct.

Comment: to me if the field can always be figure out during initialize then null is a bad idea. But its totally correct otherwise.

Comment: I don't know anything about EF but in C# you can make a variable nullable quite easily. 0 is NOT the same as NULL. Sure a numeric datatype in C# will default to 0 but if you make it a nullable type it won't default to anything. You just have to handle it or you get the object not set to an instance error.

Comment: This question is opinion based really, having said that... I strongly disagree with your team lead. nullable types are there for a reason, don't use 0 or any other magic number to indicate no value.

Comment: I completely disagree with @Trey - it is never a good idea to use a magic value, and especially not when it may turn up as the answer to a calculation.

Comment: @Steve, I don't say about properties, which always can be set during init.

Comment: If a value is optional then it should be null-able. His argument about it being "difficult" to use SQL & Entities with null-able types says more about his level of understanding of EF than anything else. EF has no issues working with null-able types. When faced with opinions like this it can help to be diplomatic and ask them to provide examples of issues or problems they see, and then demonstrate how those issues can be removed. Often these are based on bad experiences with older versions, or just bad practices that have been picked up and defaulted to.

Comment: Fair enough guys, Steve Py was pretty dead on, though I did not actually ever say it was difficult.  Good luck Oleg, you've got a great bunch of guys here who love EF that can help.